# Better way to write a column start update function when writing to xlsx

Tags: r, function

I am currently writing multiple dataframes to 1 sheet using `openxlsx`, each with a nice open column between them. I want to write the dataframes to this single sheet as the I want to have them all on one sheet to analyse and not have to go through 10 sheets to do so.

My toy dataset looks as follows:

```
> random_dat
   Letters Count Letters.1    Count.1 Letters.2 Count.2 Final
1        A     1        A1 0.21477659         Z      10   Z10
2        A     2        A2 0.92217670         X      12   X12
3        A     3        A3 0.49196523         T      14   T14
4        B     1        B1 0.08086314         Y      16   Y16
5        B     2        B2 0.80177983         Z      18   Z18
6        A     4        A4 0.35970442         X      20   X20
7        B     3        B3 0.21102868         T      22   T22
8        C     1        C1 0.75816713         Y      24   Y24
9        C     2        C2 0.59261425         Z      26   Z26
10       D     1        D1 0.73484393         X      28   X28
11       A     5        A5 0.32830008         T      30   T30
12       C     3        C3 0.21672748         Y      32   Y32
```

Now I create my workbook and worksheet and create 3 different `data.frames` that will be written to my `xlsx` file.

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb,sheetName = "Output")
df1 <- random_dat[,1:2]
df2 <- random_dat[,2:3]
df3 <- random_dat[,3:7]
```

I am now ready to start writing these to my file:

```
writeData(wb, sheet = "Output", df1, startCol = 1, startRow = 1, xy = NULL,
          colNames = TRUE, rowNames = FALSE, headerStyle = NULL, withFilter = FALSE,
          keepNA = FALSE)
start_col <- 1
start_col <- start_col+dim(df1)[2]+1

writeData(wb, sheet = "Output", df2, startCol = start_col, startRow = 1, xy = NULL,
          colNames = TRUE, rowNames = FALSE, headerStyle = NULL, withFilter = FALSE,
          keepNA = FALSE)

start_col <- start_col+dim(df1)[2]+1

writeData(wb, sheet = "Output", df1, startCol = start_col, startRow = 1, xy = NULL,
          colNames = TRUE, rowNames = FALSE, headerStyle = NULL, withFilter = FALSE,
          keepNA = FALSE)

start_col <- start_col+dim(df1)[2]+1

saveWorkbook(wb, "output.xlsx")
```

As you can see, after each write, I update the start column using `dim()` of the data and add 1 as to leave an empty column between `data.frames`.

Isnt there an easier way to create a global function which could update the column counter variable for me in a simple way with only getting the last written `data.frame` as input, for example:

```
update_col<-function(df,envir = .GlobalEnv)
{
  if(!("start_col" %in% ls())) start_col<<-1
  start_col<<-start_col + dim(df)[2]
}

update_col(df1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something untested and using as you suggest globalEnv variables:

```
mywriteData <- function(wb, sheet="output",df, first=TRUE,...){
  if first {
    previous_Ncol <<- 0
    start_col <<- 1
  } 
  start_col <<- start_col+previous_Ncol
  writeData(wb, sheet = "Output", df, startCol = start_col, ...)
previous_Ncol <<- previous_Ncol + ncol(df)
}
```

Now something better: create a list of your dataset and create equivalent function based on the list with a loop, incremeting counters in loop  - this prevent using GlobalEnv (exerice)

Or even better, have list of data.frame, and use `do.call("cbind",dataframe_list)` (assumed they all have same number of rows...)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted as I am saving my data frames to a list object to which I can now apply this function over